# Is there any disadvantage on using desktop ssd for raid server storage?

Tags: raid, ssd

I know that it's necessary to use enterprise SSD for Raid server storage, but the company I work for cannot afford that kind of SSD, (even the recommended SAS HDD is too expensive). This limits my options to using a desktop HDD or, like the situation I'm proposing, a desktop SSD.

One thing that concerns me is that I have read about decreased lifespan on SSD drives using RAID 5, but I would like to know if the SSD lifespan would really be shortened if the server traffic is about 1GB written per day at most.

How long could this server run if we use an 8 WD Green 2TB (WDS200T2G0A) before one disk fails?

Take into account that I'm not asking for compatibility because the company has another server that uses SATA drives instead the SAS that are recommended, and it's been up and running for over 8 years, (albeit without the desired speed, but still working).

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that those SSD are for a Dell Poweredge 2900 Server and it only support 2TB SAS/SATA Max per each drive (8 bay RAID). It has PCIE slots (I don't know which generation) but i see really hard to make purchasing department aware of get SSD M2 Drives and the nedded adapter.

Thanks for your comments i'm analyzing all the responses.

Comment: Find their metrics about life time and calculate yourself. There are two of them: TBW = terabytes written, that's how many data you can write to the drive during its lifetime; DWPD = drive writes per day, that's how many times you can fully rewrite a drive per day for it to last the advertised warranty period. // That said, this question fits SuperUser better than here.

Comment: Writing 1GB a day sounds tiny these days.  Do they even /need/ SSDs?

Comment: @PhillW. Problem is 2TB CMR drives are rare these days, I think, and SMR sucks. I would avoid the WD Green series though. IMO it's too "cheap" for anything but "expendable data". Even their Blue series feels kinda "cheap" these days (and they are inexpensive anyway). (Although with the given light usage, they probably won't die soon anyway.)

Comment: The TBW of a consumer grade SSD is at least about 500x its capacity, so with 1GB/day you will never wear them out... But are you sure about the 1GB/day? It looks really nothing.

Comment: @PhillW. It's a server used to development, but in some point it was turned into production server for some processes, so this server is not one of the main servers but we  there is the possibility that in some point it could be turned in production server because one of the main servers could fail.

Comment: @TomYan I agree with you about WD quallity, but searching all my options it only could be 2TB Exos 7200rpm Seagate, 2TB WD RED 7200rpm or 2TB WD Green SSD, mainly it's for the price but it's server compatibility reason also.

Comment: @PierU 1GB per day was my estimation because it's a server that doesn't hold main processes and based on some metrics i got from cockpit. Thanks for your opinion i hope the ssd could last some years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd argue that differences between enterprise grade vs. consumer grade SSD's probably aren't or aren't entirely or for the most part, physical:

- Differences at firmware level, firmware policies.

If you have the time, watch [this video](https://youtu.be/fqzv2YXMFRs?list=PLSL85pYTZnmshZ-mVYxEsT6DifuIUp4AX) (Intel staff discussing silent corruption in SSD's and how to handle this) and then decide, if you like me, can not help thinking the biggest difference between enterprise <> consumer SSD's are decisions with regards to firmware. How many and what errors are acceptable, the behavior of the drive on certain errors, are all matter of policy.

At some point they discuss certain type of errors, the enterprise SSD's will as they call it "brick themselves" while the consumer grade drives carry on and potentially return corrupt data, and such behavior is all configured at the firmware level.

Also, better endurance and performance can be simply achieved by a 'policy decision' at the firmware level: how much real-estate (NAND) do we reserve for over-provisioning? Again, main differences between enterprise grade and consumer grade are decided by how firmware of the drive is configured:

```
Intel S4600       240GB
Intel S4600       480GB
Intel S4500       240GB
Intel S4500       480GB
Samsung 860 Pro   256GB
Samsung 860 Pro   512GB
Samsung 850 Pro   256GB
Samsung 850 Pro   512GB
```

The Intel enterprise class SSD's in the above example don't have less NAND installed, the reduced capacities are due to more real-estate being reserved for overprovisioning at the firmware level. IOW the enterprise grade Intel S4600 240GB and the consumer grade Samsung 860 Pro 256GB have the exact same amount of NAND installed, but it's used differently. Simply assigning more NAND to overprovisioning will have an effect on both performance as well as endurance.

Speed can be configured at the firmware level: An x amount of NAND can be configured to function as 'pseudo SLC NAND' and used as high speed cache area. So, large area for enterprise, smaller area for consumer grade.

- Warranty and conditions related to that. I'll leave this to your imagination.

**Is it really that simple?**

Of course, those decisions at firmware level to a degree determine how reliable your SSD will be and how long it will last. So I am not arguing there is no difference or that the difference is without substance. But every decision towards better performance and endurance comes at a cost in the form of reduced capacity if we assume same amount of physical NAND installed.

*To a degree* you can 'simulate' what enterprise grade SSD's accomplish at the firmware level: For example, by excluding 10% LBA space from being partitioned or used by the array, you're effectively over-provisioning. But OTOH you *can not* decide on the percentage of NAND that is overprovisioned to handle degrading blocks.

[image]

Also, *there may be actual physical differences*, as an example enterprise grade SSD's are often for example better protected against sudden loss of power in the (physical) form of an array of super capacitors on the PCB.

[image]

IOW, you can decide to use consumer grade SSD's in your array, but it comes at the cost of less reliability, endurance and performance. To a degree you can circumvent the problems with consumer grade SSD's by implementing some form over overprovisioning yourself.

**True comparison**

If you want to make a true comparison you should look at hardware differences. If for given capacity enterprise drive uses MLC NAND vs QLC NAND in some consumer drive *then* you found a substantial difference.

If an enterprise SSD features super capacitors for power loss protection and the consumer level drive does not, *then* you find a true difference.

You have to research beyond what the sales brochure tells you.

**Overprovisioning makes the consumer SSD more expensive per GB**

Of course when you reserve more space for overprovisioning then this makes price per usable GB higher. This needs to be taken into account when comparing enterprise vs consumer grade SSD. At some point an actual enterprise grade SSD is probably the more sane choice even when funds are tight.

Comment: Really good information. You didn't only say "don't do it", you said why not and proposed an alternative, that it's not a magical solution and not the ideal, i know, but it's very important to take in count for any solution that we decide. Thanks

Comment: "I'd argue that biggest differences between enterprise grade vs. consumer grade SSD's probably aren't or aren't entirely or for the most part, physical:" and I will tell you this is crap. Really crap of an uninformed. Among other things, Enterprise drives have higher endurance - due to oversubscribing (i.e. you get way more hardware than you sign up for - while you make it sound like, getting more hardware is not a policy or firmware decision) and they (pretty much always) have condensates to handle power failure gracefully. Try coding a physical condensator in firmware, please.

Comment: @TomTom I assume you stopped reading after first sentence and went straight into a tantrum?

Comment: No, but you make things sound special when they are not. I have yet to see a single enterprise drive without capacitators you claim they are only in high end drives. Nope, all enterprise drives.

Comment: In context I meant enterprise grade when I said high end. But even then still you can resort to a more mild comment and still correct rather than disqualify the whole thing as crap. I didn't make it sound special, it's an example of an actual physical difference.

Comment: the top level assumption/conclusion is incorrect. the NAND is not the same and the SSD Controller is not the same. expect to have much higher performance, and endurance and reliability for Enterprise at a higher price. see my answer for more details.

Comment: As I explain, reserving more NAND for overprovisioning affects both endurance and performance.

Answer (score 4):

NAND engineer here.

Enterprise-grade (enterprise) will have higher performance (usually Random I/O), much higher endurance (up to 10k program/erase cycles vs 1k or 3k), and much higher data retention in the off state (up to 5-10yr retention vs 3mths-1yr). You should expect to pay more.

Whether consumer-grade (consumer) will suffice will depend on your usage model. If you expect to tax the endurance of the drives (lots of P/E cycles in the terabyte range like commercial video editing), I think you will benefit from enterprise. With current technology, you should not need to be concerned with data retention but more so with drive endurance. If most of your use is going to be reads...forget about enterprise; you will get great value from consumer. If you can get two consumer in RAID1 for the price of one enterprise, I think you see my point.

The benefits of enterprise-grade:

1. Superior performance in all aspects mentioned above (performance, endurance, reliability). Customers like Google, Amazon, and Microsoft are buying these for the Cloud.
2. Guarantee the above with higher temperature tolerances (up to 85°C vs 70°C).
3. Robustness to extreme use. Enterprise drives are tested with the assumption that the customer will be driving them 24/7 with no downtime (constant reads from thousands or millions of people accessing the cloud). This means that garbage collection and other nice features to maintain data integrity need to be designed to meet those requirements.

The differences at the manufacturer level (mostly as a response to [@Joep van Steen's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1787995/)):

The physical NAND itself is the same (same semiconductor design and fabrication process) but once the wafer is finished, everything downstream will be different between the enterprise and consumer-grade. This starts immediately when the wafer testing begins all the way to assembly and package testing.

The NAND firmware (**not** SSD firmware) is already different in terms of performance trims (program, read and erase algorithms). To be specific the algorithms are tuned to meet certain performance and reliability requirements. In order for data to be written faster and last longer, the algorithm must be tuned for it. Not all dies on a wafer can meet this requirement even if you try. Typically the entire wafer is designated to be passable or not at a target market segment or else gets diverted to a lower segment.

The SSD firmware is also different, and this is where the error handling methods may be more in number and more complex. This is not the same as **overprovisioning** which is an allocation of hidden spare blocks with which bad user blocks can be replaced. Overprovisioning tries to ensure that the user retains the advertised total usable capacity through the life of the product (because of the growth of bad blocks through use)--but it is a separate concept from data integrity. If your programmed data cannot be recovered at a later date, it is lost. No amount of spare blocks will compensate for data loss. Now of course if an entire block is lost, there are also methods to recover the entire block using block-level ECC (other blocks are being used as ECC for the bad block)--but this may or may not involve spare blocks in the overprovisioning.

Aside from the NAND and the SSD controller, you also have passive components on the board that will be of better quality to meet the higher requirements of enterprise.

Comment: Thanks. But you make a bit of a strawman of my answer. For example I never said overprovisioning has anything to do with bad blocks, that's not how I understand overprovisioning is used. One of the main effects of overprovisioning *is* endurance and speed, and so the decision how much NAND real-estate we put aside for this directly affects performance and endurance. And this *is* I would argue largely a policy level decision. TBH your first paragraphs sound like a sales brochure. Anyway, this is not a discussion forum so your answer should be good answer without referring to  relying on mine.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: enterprise disks of all kinds have larger *MTBF*, so they last longer (like, a lot). Furthermore, usually enterprise disks have warrantee - usually *NBD* change in case of failure. Disks from the nearest mall also have warrantee, but in a more flexible (for the vendor) way.

Other than that - no disadvantages. If you cannot afford enterprise disks - use consumer ones.

Comment: Yeah, one reason is that the company cannot afford good SAS or SSD drives, but i forgot mention that the server is old and only support 2TB drives. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> but the company i work for cannot afford that kind of SSD,

They are bankrupt. Because I just checked - moving some servers from HDD to SSD and while more expensive, definitely not prohibitively. On top, I cannot get 8TB 2.5" drives, so I can update capacity on top from the current 2TB drives.

> desktop SSD

There is quite a chance that this is a really bad idea, depending on what you do on the server. It may work as an OS drive but...
their write endurance before 'out of warranty' is often bad to comically so - even unsuitable for a desktop development machine. I have seen drives with about 70GB written per day in the calculation. Good for "casual" desktop (office work).

Enterprise SSD have a LOT more - and I mean a LOT - more endurance. I just planned a move to Kingston DC600 - mixed workload SATA, because SATA in those servers is what I have - and the 8TB model has about 14k Terabyte write endurance. That is a LOT of writes per day.

I have once made your mistake - put a number of 1TB around desktop into a build server. We used them up IN 6 months.

Comment: 6 months!? Wow, it was really fast. As i said to @drookie i forgot to mention that is a really old server, but we work with what we have. The options in my country to use the server are limited because the maximmun size of each drive only could be 2TB, in fact lattely i haven't seen any 2TB SAS Drive on webpages from local stores, most of them says it's sold out. Are they bankrupt? almost XD haha it's very hard to make then buy escential things for my it department.

Comment: Hosting VM's with multiple build agents - basically writing pretty much non stop.